# Load multiple files to multiple arrays with for loop and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an unknown number of txt files and each file contains two columns for numbers.
I am trying to make a python script that loads whatever it finds in that directory and create numpy 1D arrays for each column automatically.
Here's my attempt in which I don't know how to update the names of the arrays and how to pass them to numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd

myfiles = [myfile for myfile in os.listdir() if myfile.endswith(".txt")]
for myfile in myfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(myfile, delimiter = "\t")
    df.columns = ["x", "y"]
```

What I need are a bunch of x1, y1, x2, y2...etc, where I can gather them in a dictionary for further manipulations.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
for i, myfile in enumerate(myfiles, 1):
    df = pd.read_csv(myfile, delimiter = "\t")
    df.columns = [f"x{i}", f"y{i}"]
```

---

```
for i, myfile in enumerate(myfiles, 1):
    df = pd.read_csv(myfile, delimiter = "\t", names=[f"x{i}", f"y{i}"], skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, using that code, I got only the last elements of the loop. Say I have 10 files, I will only get x10 y10 !